# HTTPS in Haskell

Tags: haskell, https

I want to interact with some HTTPS google APIs in Haskell (initially, at least, [ClientLogin](https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin)).

However, the [HTTP package's documentation for `Network.HTTP` explicitly says "This package only supports HTTP; it does not support HTTPS. Attempts to use HTTPS result in an error."](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.0.9/docs/Network-HTTP.html)

So what packages are available that do support HTTPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need only client side library?

I used [http-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit) and [http-streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-streams), so I recommend them. My choose for current projects is `http-conduit`.